# How to detect that the mapbox viewport have been moved significantly to "search within this area"?

Tags: react-map-gl

I am using "react-map-gl", nothing of the sort was available out of the box.
What is the most preferred method for detecting this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good place for the useEffect hook.

`viewport` state changes whenever a user pans or zooms, so if you place these three properties in the useEffect dependency array, whatever logic within `useEffect` body will be invoked whenever the viewport state updates.

Example

```
useEffect(() => {

  // implement your search logic here
    
}, [viewport.latitude, viewport.longitude, viewport.zoom]);
```